# Axios promise in a loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, async-await, axios

In React, I want to pass a function `getRepos()` to `componentDidMount()`. `getRepos()` waits for another function which passes data from API call. I want to be able to put all promises in one array and then resolve it. How do I do that? Here's what I've got so far:

```html
async getRepos() {
    const tmpRepos = [];
    const numPages = await this.getOrgPages();
    for (let page = 1; page <= numPages; page += 1) {
      axios.get(`https://api.github.com/orgs/angular/repos?page=${page}&per_page=100&${API_KEY}`)
    }
    axios.all(tmpRepos).then(res => console.log(res));
}
```

But just logs an empty array

Comment: You'd done everything except push to `tmpRpos`.

Comment: Side note: What if the number of pages changes while you're doing this? Perhaps better to just query starting from 1 until you get an error?

Comment: I get the number of pages in response to the API call in getOrgPages() function

Comment: Hence the *"...while you're doing this..."* part of the comment. Think race condition.

Comment: Good question. I will need to think about it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a new array, and fill it by results of `axios.get` calls, use this array in `axios.all`:

```
async getRepos() {
    const ops = [];
    const numPages = await this.getOrgPages();
    for (let page = 1; page <= numPages; page += 1) {
      let op = axios.get(`https://api.github.com/orgs/angular/repos?page=${page}&per_page=100&${API_KEY}`);
      ops.push(op);
    }

    let res = await axios.all(ops);
    console.log(res);
}
```